# Can Doppler effect produce effect beyond visible region

Tags: doppler-effect

Can Doppler effect produce changes beyond visible region ? Like suppose a star that is moving towards us emitting a violet color but due to Doppler effect we are receiving wavelengths lying in region of Ultra violet (UV region ). IS it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory: Yes.

In practice: No, because you would need a star with extraordinary high speed.

Example: Suppose you find a star approaching us with velocity 30000 km/s
(which is 10 % of the speed of light).
Then violet light ($\lambda =$ 400 nm) would be doppler-shifted by 10 % to near UV ($\lambda =$ 360 nm).

But stars in our galaxy are much slower, typically slower than 100 km/s
(see [Stellar_kinematics - High-velocity stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_kinematics#High-velocity_stars)).

Comment: There's plenty of objects (both of galactic scale as well as individual (supernova) stars in other galaxies) whose cosmological redshifts are high enough to shift the entire visible spectrum out of human visibility.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You are right about many far objects with large *red*-shift
(due to Hubble-effect). But the question was about objects with *blue*-shift.